# How do you install Bazel in python2 environment?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, bazel

How do you install Bazel in a python2 environment? The tensorflow website has an error posted on the such as this "Caution: Because of an bazel bug, we only support building the Android demo app within a Python 2 environment", (See related Bazel installation on windows">Bazel installation on Windows). How do you install Bazel in a python2 environment( to get apps working on Windows, using bazel)? The Bazel install in a python2 environment may be a workaround for the error shown earlier on the Tensorflow website, they do not seem to have any other workarounds known.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install Python2 (e.g. [from python.org: Python 2.7.15, 64-bit version](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi)[1])
2. Use [the `--python_path` flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html)[2] to tell Bazel where's the Python interpreter.

For example if you installed Python2 under `c:\python2`, run Bazel like so:

```
c:\tensorflow> bazel build --python_path=c:/python2/python.exe //foo:bar
```

If you want Bazel to always use this flag in this workspace (`c:\tensorflow`), add the following line to `c:\tensorflow\.bazelrc`:

```
build --python_path=c:/python2/python.exe
```

(You may need to add this line every time you re-run the `configure` script.)

Update: [here's more info about `.bazelrc` files](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#bazelrc)[3], what they are, where they are, how to specify them.

---

[1] https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi

[2] https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html

[3] https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#bazelrc